# How to stop process from .BAT file?

Tags: file, process, batch-file

So I have process I started from one bat file. How to stop it from another?

Comment: `taskkill -im exename.exe` will forcefully terminate the process. Is this what you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to write a Windows .bat file to kill processes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822/any-way-to-write-a-windows-bat-file-to-kill-processes)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To terminate a process you know the name of, try:

```
taskkill /IM notepad.exe
```

This will ask it to close, but it may refuse, offer to "save changes", etc.  If you want to forcibly kill it, try:

```
taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Indeed the option without /F asks the program to close nicely. The program can then still decide to not close at all. I have a program that minimizes to a tray icon when the close button is pressed and that is exactly what happens. The /F option forcibly exits it.

Comment: `taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe` better in most cases for me. `taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe` throws errors at me from tasks that don't have save dialogs. They don't close properly and different things can happen (the program may stay open, even after the dialog is closed).  I wouldn't want an error to be generated in the background, either, so I recommend `/F /IM` unless it's Word.exe or something.

Answer (score 5):

As TASKKILL might be unavailable on some Home/basic editions of windows here some alternatives:

```
TSKILL processName
```

or

```
TSKILL PID
```

Have on mind that `processName` should not have the `.exe` suffix and is limited to 18 characters.

Another option is `WMIC` :

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "Caption Like 'MyProcess.exe'" Call Terminate
```

wmic offer even more flexibility than taskkill .With `wmic Path win32_process get` you can see the available fileds you can filter.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to kill all instances of Chrome when the browser won't open (recent Chrome annoying bug). You can end up with a bunch of chrome.exe processes running from 2 to ?.
I just did a clean and quick check to see if it's running and kill it if it is. The pause at the end is only so I can view the results, it isn't needed.

```
@echo off
:again
taskkill /F /IM "chrome.exe"
if errorlevel=0 goto end
if errorlevel=1 goto again
:end
pause
```

it works well for me

Comment: This answer is not adding noting new that wasn't mentioned on another answers and also it is confuse because you've just added your script made to solve a different problem then the mentioned by the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you start a process from a batch file, it starts as a separate process with no hint towards the batch file that started it (since this would have finished running in the meantime, things like the parent process ID won't help you).

If you know the process name, and it is unique among all running processes, you can use `taskkill`, like @IVlad suggests in a comment.

If it is not unique, you might want to look into jobs. These terminate all spawned child processes when they are terminated.

Answer (score 1):

**taskkill /F /IM notepad.exe** this is the best way to kill the task from task manager.

Answer (score 1):

> Edit:
> `call runntaskkill.bat` is changed to `call taskkillapp.bat` or else it will end up with the same file.

You can make two batch files. One named runtaskkill.bat and another named taskkillapp.bat. To the file runtaskkill.bat add the following code:

`call taskkillapp.bat [filenamehere]`.

And to taskkill.bat:

`taskkill /f /im %1`.

Just make sure that the two files are in the same directory (folder).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to kill one or more processes from a .bat file.

Step 1. Open a preferred text editor and create a new file.

step 2. To kill one process use the 'taskkill' command, with the '/im' parameter that specifies the image name of the process to be terminated. Example:

```
taskkill /im examplename.exe
```

To 'force' kill a process, use the '/f' parameter which specifies that processes be forcefully terminated. Example:

```
taskkill /f /im somecorporateprocess.exe
```

To kill more than one process you repeat the first part of step 2 with the appropriate processes for the process name. Example:

```
taskkill /im examplename.exe
taskkill /im examplename1.exe
taskkill /im examplename2.exe
```

or

```
taskkill /f /im examplename.exe
taskkill /f /im examplename1.exe
taskkill /f /im examplename2.exe
```

Step 3. Save your file to your desired location with the .bat extension.

Step 4. Click the newly created bat file to run it.

Answer (score 0):

To just click file and run with ***no*** message "*press any key to continue*"

```
@echo off
call taskkill /f /im adb.exe /im OfficeClickToRun.exe
pause>nul
exit /b 0
```

add any amount of processes:

/im `the_process_name.exe`

TIP:

Create a shortcut of the *.bat file* somewhere (you can drag it to start menu/all programs) , go to the shortcut file properties and add a **shortcut key**

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use PowerShell?

```
Stop-Process -Name notepad
```

And if you are in a batch file:

```
powershell -Command "Stop-Process -Name notepad"
powershell -Command "Stop-Process -Id 4232"
```