# How can I kill proces in Win2008R2 whenever it starts?

Tags: windows, printing, canon-sdk

I have problem in my Windows2008R2 server, wich I use it like print server. Driver from Canon, CNABGSWK.EXE start in random times and fill my processor on 100% and all print jobs stopped.

Any idea how to stop/fix this?
Maybe with batch script, which always run in background and kill this process when it starts?

tnx

Comment: rename the file....

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to either make a batch script to check if the process is running every X amount of seconds/minutes and kill it, or you can rename the file to something like CNABGSWK.EXE.BAK.

Some other Stack Overflow links to help you if you're making the script:

[How to stop process from .BAT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888851/how-to-stop-process-from-bat-file)

[How to check if a process is running via a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)