# How to close a program with taskkill and avoid any prompting from the program

Tags: file, batch-file, command

I've written a batch file to close few applications. One of my application asks confirmation message and requires to click on 'Yes' to close it. Is there any command that close these kind of application via batch file?

```
@echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq program1.exe"
tasklist /fi "imagename eq program2.exe"
(
taskkill /f /im program1.exe /t
taskkill /f /im program2.exe /t
timeout /t 2
start "" "program3.bat"
timeout /t 20
start "" "program4.bat"
timeout /t 30
start "" "program1.exe"
timeout /t 2
start "" "program2.exe"
)
pause
```

Comment: What application asks for confirmation?

Comment: when i click exit option it asks "Are you sure to want to exit?" at this point i need to click on yes to close it

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. I was asking which program you are trying to close that is asking whether you are sure you want to esit. However it seems that this info is unneeded judging by the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Type:

```
taskkill /f /im "process name"
```

It has been answered already here:
[Any way to write a Windows .bat file to kill processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822/any-way-to-write-a-windows-bat-file-to-kill-processes)

Comment: That is pretty much what I have just put.

Comment: You forgot of /f para. which is for forcing to close

Comment: i am using the above mentioned command but it need user interaction. but i want it to close without user interaction. is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
Taskkill /im [name of program]
```

For more infomation have a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb491009.aspx

Use /f to force close the application.

```
Taskkill /f /im [name of program]
```

Comment: i am using the above mentioned command but it need user interaction. but i want it to close without user interaction. is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the bottom code. If so can you show us your batch file.

Comment: @echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq program1.exe"
tasklist /fi "imagename eq program2.exe"
(
taskkill /f /im program1.exe /t
taskkill /f /im program2.exe /t
timeout /t 2
start "" "program3.bat"
timeout /t 20
start "" "program4.bat"
timeout /t 30
start "" "program1.exe"
timeout /t 2
start "" "program2.exe"
)
pause

Comment: Try it with out the /t para.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool that presses the key for you - such as: SENDKEYS or the more reliable AutoIt.